# How to parse a stringified array in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

How to parse any stringified array such as "[\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]" in Swift? It should return a JSON array such as ["Bob", "Tim", "Tina"].

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I could not find any answer for a generic stringified array where the structure of the array elements are not known.

Comment: you cant, ["Bob", "Tim", "Tina"] is not an JSON array, it is still an array of String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this, Works for me every time:

```
let jsonText = "[\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]"

    var array: [String]?

    if let data = jsonText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

        do {
            array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String]

            if let myArray = array {
                 print(myArray)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

It prints : `["Bob", "Tim", "Tina"]`
Hope it helps!!

Comment: @conundrum Sure I'll add the support for all kind of JSON serialization

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String
{      
    func decodeUrl() -> String
    {
        return self.removingPercentEncoding!
    }
}

extension Data
{
    func dataToJSON() -> Any? {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: [])
        } catch let myJSONError {
            print(myJSONError)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
if let data = your_stringified_array.decodeUrl().data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            if let jsonc = data.dataToJSON() {
                print(jsonc)
            }
        }
```

Result is in `AnyObject`.

Comment: I marked the other one as correct as it came earlier. I could not mark both as correct. Thanks.